# Trying to generate a 2-column table using PHP from JSON data

Tags: php

This should be a fairly simple problem, however I cannot for the life of me get it to work right.

I have JSON data in the form of an array like so and I am trying to generate a 2-column table where every 2 elements in the array take up a row.

```
[
    {
        "type": "Ground",
        "field_location": "",
        "field_user": "",
    },
    {
        "type": "Water",
        "field_location": "",
        "field_user": "",
    },
    {
        "type": "Sewer",
        "field_location": "",
        "field_user": "",
    },
    {
        "type": "Tap",
        "field_location": "",
        "field_user": "",
    }
]
```

I have overly simplified the code, however the function currently looks as follows.

```
function generateHtml($jsonDoc){
    $html = "";
    $html .= "<table>";
    $count = 0;   

    foreach ($jsonDoc as $key => $value) {
        $count ++;

        if ($count % 2 == 0) 
            $html .= "<tr>";

        $html .= "<td>";
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            if(!empty($val))
                $html .= $key.":".$val."<br />";
        }
        $html .= "</td>";

        if ($count % 2 == 0) 
            $html .= "</tr>";
        // $count ++;
    }
    $html .= "</table>";

    print($html);
}
```

The resulting HTML output always seems to come out as follows and I cannot seem to understand what is missing.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Ground</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Water</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sewer</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tap</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

as opposed to

````
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Ground</td>
        <td>Water</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Sewer</td>
        <td>Tap</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```
which is what I am looking for.
````

Comment: there is two $key variables first change its name, it is creating ambiguity

Comment: One simple(r) way to achieve this, would be to use `array_chunk` to split your original data into an array of arrays, and then just use two nested loops to generate the output. That also eliminates the need to do any modulo-on-loop-counter magic.

Comment: @SanjitBhardwaj Very good suggestion. Actual code does follow this.

Comment: @misorude Thank you for the suggestion. Will definitely look into this as it may better suite the original code

Comment: I added an answer showing how that can be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple(r) way to achieve this, would be to use `array_chunk` to split your original data into an array of arrays, and then just use two nested loops to generate the output.

In the outer loop, you create the table row (output `<tr>` before, and `</tr>` after), and in the inner loop, you create a table cell for each item.

```
function generateHtml($jsonDoc){
    $data = array_chunk($jsonDoc, 2); // split this into an array of arrays,
                                      // containing two of the items each
    $html = '<table>';

    foreach ($data as $row) { // loop over the first level
      $html .= '<tr>';
      foreach ($row as $cell) { // loop over the second level
        $html .= '<td>'.$cell->type.'</td>';
      }
      $html .= '</tr>';
    }
    $html .= '</table>';

    print($html);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function generateHtml($jsonDoc){
    $html = "";
    $html .= "<table>";
    $count = 1;   

    foreach ($jsonDoc as $key => $value) {
        //$count ++;

        if ($count % 2 != 0) 
            $html .= "<tr>";

        $html .= "<td>";
        foreach ($value as $key => $val) {
            if(!empty($val))
                $html .= $key.":".$val."<br />";
        }
        $html .= "</td>";

        if ($count % 2 == 0) 
            $html .= "</tr>";
        $count ++;
    }
    $html .= "</table>";

    print($html);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I see the problem seems to have been a flaw in my logic, specifically that initial if statement that opened the `<tr>`